# Python Elasticsearch aggregated query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am struggling to get an aggregated response based on a query... for example, in Kibana visualization, after creating a table with the aggregations and query I need, I can view the request by going inside the visualization and Inspect -> View:Requests -> Request. This gives me the entire request, structured like this:

```
{
 "aggs":{...},
  "size": 0,
  "fields":[...],
  "script_fields": {},
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "runtime_mappings": {},
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "query": {
    "bool":{...}
  }
}
```

How can i obtain the same dataset that is displayed in Kibana Visualization with the API?
I tried translating the API Request fields to the es.search() function like this:

```
result = es.search(
index=index,
fields=[ ...],
script_fields={},
stored_fields=[
    "*"
],
runtime_mappings={},
_source={
    "excludes": []
},
query={...},
aggs={...},

size = 0,
scroll = '5m'
)
```

But the data is not aggregated correctly, like in the Kibana Visualization.
Another strange behaviour is that if i completely remove the aggs = {...} from es.search(), it gives me the same dataset.

Note: I am using elasticsearch module 7.16.1

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The query is working fine, the aggregated data is returned in the "aggregations" section of the response, which is separate from the "hits" section.